# PHP, easier way to get array values without warnings

Tags: php

Dudes,

is there a more concise way to write the statement below? If I don't check if an array key exists I get a PHP warning. However, the below is a bit too, ehm, wordy.

Thanks!

```
$display_flag = false;
if (array_key_exists('display_flag',$pref_array) { 
    $display_flag = $pref_array['display_flag']; 
}
```

Comment: fyi, you are missing a close bracket ) on your second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it is fine, as you should validate if the value actually exists, but you could also do a ternary op:

```
$display_flag = (isset($pref_array['display_flag'])) ? (bool) $pref_array['display_flag'] : false;
```

I typecast the contents of display_flag to bool if it is set, so you are ensured a boolean value in either case.

Also you could (but I don't recommend it), squelch the warning with the @:

```
$display_flag = @$pref_array['display_flag'];
```

Answer (score 10):

Since PHP 7 you can use the new [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

```
$display_flag = $pref_array['display_flag'] ?? false;
```

Answer (score 8):

If `$display_flag` is a boolean:

```
$display_flag = isset($pref_array['display_flag']) && $pref_array['display_flag'];
```

If it's a string:

```
$display_flag = isset($pref_array['display_flag']) ? $pref_array['display_flag'] : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get the $pref_array from wherever

$default_prefs = array(
  "display_flag" => false,
);

$pref_array = array_merge($default_prefs, $pref_array);

// Now you know it's always defined with default values
```

Answer (score -2):

Another simpler option is:

```
array_get($variable, 'keyName', null)
```

The third argument is the default value.

Comment: This is only available if you are using Laravel.  https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers